# sqlalchemy named cursor not found when using sqlalchemy.sql.text()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2, alembic

This runs fine:

```
with conn.connection.cursor(name='migration_cursor') as ss_cur:
    ss_cur.execute("SELECT id, stuff FROM cart WHERE stuff_type={}".format(some_variable))
```

However, this fails:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
with conn.connection.cursor(name='migration_cursor') as ss_cur:
    ss_cur.execute(text("SELECT id, stuff FROM cart WHERE stuff_type=:some_variable"), some_variable=some_variable)
```

with this error message:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: cursor "migration_cursor" does not exist
```